# In Python subprocess, what is the difference between using Popen() and check_output()?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

Take the shell command "cat file.txt" as an example.

With Popen, this could be run with

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("cat file.txt", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = task.stdout.read()
```

With check_output, one could run

```
import subprocess
command=r"""cat file.log"""
output=subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

These appears to be equivalent. What is the difference with regards to how these two commands would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen` is the class that defines an object used to interact with an external process. `check_output()` is just a wrapper around an instance of `Popen` to examine its standard output. Here's the definition from Python 2.7 (sans docstring):

```
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

(The definition is quite a bit different, but is still ultimately a wrapper around an instance of `Popen`.)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#exceptions):

> `check_call()` and `check_output()` will raise `CalledProcessError` if the called process returns a non-zero return code.